# format for today's date in hive in yyyymmdd format

Tags: hive

I am trying to write a hive query to get the data from today's partition.  Here's my query:

```
select * from testtable
where data_dt ='date +%Y%m%d';
```

I need help converting the date to `yyyyMMdd` format.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please include the full response this query gets and explain why it's not what you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from mytable 
where mydate=regexp_replace(to_date(from_unixtimestamp())),'-','')
;
```

When I test using:

```
select regexp_replace(to_date(from_unixtimestamp())),'-','') as yyyyMMdd from dual;
```

I get the output:  20150723

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of functions in hive that can be used to retrieve today's date in desired format.

Try this:

**select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'yyyyMMdd') from table_name;**

**unix_timestamp():** this function returns a unix timestamp.

**from_unixtime():** this function is used to return date in desired format.

for further information about the built-in functions in hive, try

**show functions;**

**describe function function_name;**

**describe function extended function_name;**